# Is there any elegant way to name a DataColumn in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Suppose I have a few columns in a DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding k}" Header="k"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding f}" Header="f"/>
  ...
```

In DataGrid BeginningEdit event hander, I want to tell which cell is in editing mode. But how do I know what e.Column is?

Preferrablely I want to give each DataColun a name (x:Name). How to do that?